# Running Total in JasperSoft Studio

Tags: jasper-reports

I am creating a running total in JasperSoft Studio and need to only display the last number not every number counted. The running total is of a column and it is only counting if it meets the criteria of the cell. Currently it is displaying every number as it counts up to the final total. All I want is the total.

Answer (score 1):

In you case, If you place the Summary Field (Variable you created to sum) in Page Footer, Or If you have a Group then in Group Footer, you will get one total Value.

Thanks,
Rajesh S